# Считывание большого текстового файла (java)

Tags: java

Есть задание - считать большой текстовый файл, отфильтровать необходимые данные из представленных, сделать с ними некоторые манипуляции и создать новый файл с этими корректированными данными. Подскажите, каким способом посоветуете читать крупные файлы? Я пользуюсь Bufferedreader-ом, но использую пока-что заглушку (небольшой файл), и не знаю потянет ли данный метод крупный файл на 10к строк. Может посоветуете более эффективные методы чтения?

Comment: покажите для начала код. сложно дать рекомендации вслепую. единственное, что вы конкретезировали - использование Bufferedreader . начиная с java 8 построчное чтение файла можно произвести более простым способом. примерно так: try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) { stream.forEach(System.out::println);}. запси, кставти, также. т.е. по сути вы можете просто эту задачу решит однострочно

Comment: Конкретнее в данный момент я использую вот такую конструкцию чтения

        try (BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(readPath))){
            wordsMass = new String[linesCount + 1];
     String line = null;
            for (int i = 0; (line = fileReader.readLine()) != null; i++){

                wordsMass[i] = fileReader.readLine();
                System.out.println(i + " " + "-" + " " + wordsMass[i]);

            }
            fileReader.close();
Учусь самостоятельно. Посоветуйте пожалуйста где почитать о предложенной вами конструкции

Comment: с чтением понятно, какие преобразования нужно сделать, как вы их делаете и как сохраняете?

Comment: @Дмитрий еще нет никаких манипуляций и записей. Нужно сделать преобразования таблицы данных расчетной программы для загрузки их в другую расчетную программу (это инженерные программы из SCad в FOK). Нужно выбрать из данных числовые соответствия определенным усилиям (вертикальная таблица), выбрать из них подходящие по критериям (определяются формулами), сформировать 5 строк подходящих по критериям и создать файл с выводами по каждой точке в определенном порядке, подходящем для загрузки данных в FOK. Не знаю, есть ли смысл загружать сюда исходный файл для понятия

Comment: @Дмитрий все манипуляции буду придумывать по ходу дела) Разбираюсь с проблемами по мере поступления)

Comment: чтение-запись в ответе. для преобразования метод transformLine(). в него приходят построчно данные из входящего файла. все, что вернете из метода, запишется в новый файл

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String inputFileName = "";
        String outputFileName = "";

        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(inputFileName))) {
            Files.write(Paths.get(outputFileName), 
                    stream
                            .map(line->transformLine(line))
                            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")).getBytes());
        }

    }

    public static String transformLine(String line) {
        //todo
        return line;
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо. я попробую. только разберусь что к чему. метод обработки и трансформации строки я понял

Comment: @micropyhcher ну так в остальном коде надо только имена входящего и исходящего файла в переменные вписать. и еще... если какие-то строки нужно просто исключить, то это можно сделать, добавив вызов фильтра в стриме. если возникнут проблемы с обработкой файла - пишите